# Python DecisionTreeRegressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have tried the following code and this error has been occuring to me

Link for DataSet is in link bellow

> ValueError
> ---> line 18 ds1_model.fit(X, y)
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Iris-setosa'

```
  import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/iris.csv'
ds1 = pd.read_csv(url)
ds1.columns = (['SepalLength' , 'SepalWidth' , 'PetalLength' , 'PetalWidth' , 'ClassLabel'])
ds1_filtered=ds1.dropna(axis=0)

y = ds1_filtered.ClassLabel

ds1_features = ['SepalLength' , 'SepalWidth' , 'PetalLength' , 'PetalWidth']
X = ds1_filtered[ds1_features]

ds1_model = DecisionTreeRegressor()

ds1_model.fit(X, y)

PredictedClassLabel = ds1_model.predict(X)
mean_absolute_error(y, PredictedClassLabel)

train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 0)
ds1_model = DecisionTreeRegressor()
ds1_model.fit(train_X, train_y)

predicitions = ds1_model.predict(val_X)
print(mean_absolute_error(val_y, predictions))
```

**can you please help to suggest or explain how to fix this?**

[DataSet Link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/iris.csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name `ClassLabel` implies, the iris dataset is a *classification* and not a regression one; hence, neither `DecisionTreeRegressor` is the correct model to use nor `mean_absolute_error` is the correct metric.

You should use a `DecisionTreeClassifier` and `accuracy_score` instead:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

iris = load_iris()
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()

train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(iris.data, iris.label, random_state = 0)
clf.fit(train_X, train_Y)

pred = clf.predict(val_X)
print(accuracy_score(val_y, pred))
```

The scikit-learn [decision tree classification tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#classification) using the said dataset can give you more ideas.

Comment: 100% correct, but it might also be worth mentioning that the specific error is due to the fact that sklearn models (classification or regression both) can't take string input, the the targets need to be encoded in some way to numeric types

Comment: What do you suggest to use?
And is it possible if I turn the ClassLabels into numbers to represent eachone of the strings and then apply regression?

Comment: I saw .. thank you so much
just for clarification accuracy_score is equivalent to the mean_absolute_error

Comment: @desertnaut Can you please take a look into this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/58900947/5904928
I am struggling for hours, couldn't find an answer.